# laravel urls missing "en" from links generated from named routes

Tags: laravel, nginx, url

My test site is http site
my live site is https site.

My test site urls are working fine with

```
$url = route('admin.taskmanager.taskmanager.edit', [$task->id]);
```

which is generating
http://example.com/app/taskmanager/taskmanagers/89/edit

but the same url in live site is generating
https://example.com/app/taskmanager/taskmanagers/89/edit

PROBLEM:
Above live site url is generating 502 gateway error.
but when I add /en to the url like
https://example.com/en/app/taskmanager/taskmanagers/89/edit
it is working.

Both are nginx platform with same conf files.

Test site which is http site is automatically adding /en
but live site with https is not adding /en to my generated urls using routes are throwing 502 error.

Any help?

@matiaslauriti my router is as below

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/taskmanager'], function(Router $router) {
    $router->bind('taskmanager', function($id) {
        return app('Modules\Taskmanager\Repositories\TaskmanagerRepository')->find($id);
    });
   
    $router->get('taskmanagers/{taskmanager}/edit', [
        'as' => 'admin.taskmanager.taskmanager.edit',
        'uses' => 'TaskmanagerController@edit',
        'middleware' => 'can:taskmanager.taskmanagers.access'
    ]);
```

Comment: It is hard to help you if you don't share what could be adding `/en`, I am 99% sure it is a middleware, can you share that? Share the route and the controller too (just in case)

Comment: can you suggest how to add locale to the generated url? I have updated my question and added my route